# How can a Microsoft Teams Bot send a chat message to a meeting?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've got a Teams bot that can create a meeting on behalf of a user, join the meeting call, play media into the meeting, and add participants to the meeting using the calling stack.  What I'd like to do though is also monitor the chat in the meeting, and/or send messages into the meeting chat.  To start with, I tried something like this:

```
ConnectorClient c = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/"), AppId, AppSecret);
var message = Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.Text = "Message from bot"; 
await c.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync("19:meeting_YzJjYjUzZmQtMjgzZi00ZjgyLTllMGMtZjQ2OWM4NmEzM2Y5@thread.v2", (Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity)message);
```

Which comes back as unauthorized.  I've used the same method for proactive bot messages to 1:1 chats by using an ID like this:

> a:1HS58qlUpMwrFUuXZ9mER5D1o8cmsrufPaG8cfaV8Zj3D6lhKCU4XYKU05UxTP1EQ0UOi0Cl3LzQFSCAOQKv_KTIXgjr5Y3nvh-ONPwC-mz71o3hFg_xmbr9HC4e9c1ff

The bot should have all the application permissions I need, including these (not a full list):

- Chat.ReadWrite.All
- Calls.Initiate.All
- OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All
- Calls.JoinGroup.All
- Calls.AccessMedia.All

I also have the following scopes set:

```
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
```

I think the problem is with the conversation ID format, which I grabbed from the meeting creation, and needed to pass into the body of the call join as the ThreadId in ChatInfo.  Presumably this should also be the messaging conversation ID.

So, my question is, is it possible to have a bot proactive message a meeting, and if so, how should I get the conversation ID for the meeting chat thread?

Comment: You need to add GroupChat scope for your Bot in app manifest. The Bot needs to install in Teams meeting chat manually, you can @Bot_Name to see that if Bot is added or not in meeting chat.

Comment: I already had those set, but hadn't mentioned it (edited the original question to include them).  In my example, the bot creates the meeting and joins the call.  The bot is listed in the meeting roster, but I can't @mention it, and it doesn't show up as a chat member if I pull the roster from graph.

Comment: Bot should be listed as chat member, try to add the bot in meeting manually only than you will get the conversation id for bot